# ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'date' Why is it not working?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax import VARMAX
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import grangercausalitytests, adfuller
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
from itertools import product


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

filepath = r'/Users/nathanielfremy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/VAR Economics/data.xlsx'
open(filepath)
macro_data = pd.read_excel(filepath, parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
print(macro_data.shape)
macro_data.head()
```

Why am I getting a value error. Date is labeled in the excel sheet.

I am expecting for it to read that column I'm guessing. I've never really ran this before.

Comment: Without seeing the contents of the excel file, there's no real way for us to help.

Comment: A wild guess: Is the column header spelled `date` or `Date`?

Answer (score 0):

You want 'Date', not 'date'.   Maybe.

If my wild guess was incorrect, you can get further by breaking down the problem a bit.   Might I suggest:

- First, be clear exactly where the error comes from.  I am guessing `pd.read_excel()` is throwing a ValueError exception?
- Try reading the data without the `parse_dates` argument.  If that works, then it likely is about parsing the date.
- Make a copy of your data with only the first two lines and try again?  If that works, then it is likely some odd date in your data.
- Make a copy with just the date column and try to read in.   If that works, then it is likely some other column in your sheet.

You are not alone in these mysteries.  It's a bit like Jane Goodall studying apes:  you try to learn what happens without worrying about every detail.  When you hit a snag, you narrow it down to something really small.

Please add your answer once you figure it out.

Keep hacking!  Keep notes.

Charles